# Is running my Unreal Tournament server like this slower than it has to be?

Tags: debian, gcc, gameserver

Unreal Tournament 2004 is an old game, and it does not run on a new server. I was said to run the server like this.

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/archive/gcc3 ./ucc-bin server BR-Serenity?game=XGame.xBombingRun?Mutator=UT2Vote51.UT2VoteXMulti,UAdminModV095b.UAdminMod,DualAssaultRifles2k4.DualAssaultRifles ini=ut2004-server.ini
```

Although this works perfectly, I wonder if running it with the old gcc3-compiler(?) makes it run slower? Is this not recommended?

The game does not run without adding this to the command-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont run it with gcc compiler, it uses your gcc3 libs.

even if you would recompile it with recent versions of gcc, i dont thnik it will have an effect. tuning other parts, e.g. disabling unneeded mods is a much better way to improve performance.